# Gradle (Android) - Multiproject dependency missing in testCompile

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have a Library project A and another Library Project B. The project B imports as a `compile` dependency the project A and I wanted also to add this same dependency for the unit tests, so I can mock some classes from project A (not importing the test folder, but the actual project).

Even with gradle sync working properly, and `./gradlew projectB:dependencies` showing the tree with the correct dependencies, in my test classes in project B I cannot access the classes from the A project.

```
dependencies {
    //Project B dependencies
    compile project(":projectA")
    testCompile project(":projectA")
}
```

Which is even more fun is that if instead of using the `project(":projectA")` aka `DefaultProjectDependency` I use the "group:artifact:version" way aka `DefaultExternalModuleDependency` by installing Project A locally, it works properly.

For me it sounds like a bug, not sure if it is an Android one or a gradle one.

Versions:

- gradle - 2.11
- android gradle plugin - 1.5.0

Also opened an issue in b.android: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201820&thanks=201820&ts=1456399375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this was an error in the Android Plugin and according to the comments in [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200952) it will be fixed in 2.0.0 beta 7.